# Unable to run elasticsearch on Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am running elasticsearch and it shows cluster health status YELLOW. The full log is as follows :

```
elastic_user@ulabsml5u:/ml_data/at3/cache/ES/ml5u/elasticsearch-6.6.0/bin$ ./elasticsearch
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[2023-04-18T03:54:16,852][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [FVvXGcx] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ml_data (192.168.0.104:/)]], net usable_space [8191.9pb], net total_space [8191.9pb], types [nfs4]
[2023-04-18T03:54:16,884][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [FVvXGcx] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2023-04-18T03:54:26,761][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [FVvXGcx] node name derived from node ID [FVvXGcxnRmGW5jQb3tw9kg]; set [node.name] to override
[2023-04-18T03:54:26,763][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [FVvXGcx] version[6.6.0], pid[25600], build[default/tar/a9861f4/2019-01-24T11:27:09.439740Z], OS[Linux/5.4.0-1081-aws/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.2/11.0.2+9-LTS]
[2023-04-18T03:54:26,763][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [FVvXGcx] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-9455954933887117697, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -Des.path.home=/ml_data/at3/cache/ES/ml5u/elasticsearch-6.6.0, -Des.path.conf=/ml_data/at3/cache/ES/ml5u/elasticsearch-6.6.0/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,253][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,255][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [parent-join]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,255][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [percolator]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,255][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,255][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [reindex]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,255][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [repository-url]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,255][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,256][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [tribe]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,256][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,256][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,256][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,256][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,256][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,257][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2023-04-18T03:54:46,258][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [FVvXGcx] no plugins loaded
[2023-04-18T03:54:55,059][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [FVvXGcx] parsed [0] roles from file [/ml_data/at3/cache/ES/ml5u/elasticsearch-6.6.0/config/roles.yml]
[2023-04-18T03:54:58,592][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [FVvXGcx] [controller/25927] [Main.cc@109] controller (64 bit): Version 6.6.0 (Build bbb4919f4d17a5) Copyright (c) 2019 Elasticsearch BV
[2023-04-18T03:54:59,794][DEBUG][o.e.a.ActionModule       ] [FVvXGcx] Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security
[2023-04-18T03:55:00,856][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [FVvXGcx] using discovery type [zen] and host providers [settings]
[2023-04-18T03:55:01,803][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [FVvXGcx] initialized
[2023-04-18T03:55:01,803][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [FVvXGcx] starting ...
[2023-04-18T03:55:03,029][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [FVvXGcx] publish_address {10.6.23.154:9300}, bound_addresses {10.6.23.154:9300}
[2023-04-18T03:55:03,159][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [FVvXGcx] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2023-04-18T03:55:06,275][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [FVvXGcx] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined), reason: new_master {FVvXGcx}{FVvXGcxnRmGW5jQb3tw9kg}{01m_Bg7WRku3h2iP-9l0Kg}{10.6.23.154}{10.6.23.154:9300}{ml.machine_memory=66784632832, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}
[2023-04-18T03:55:06,281][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [FVvXGcx] new_master {FVvXGcx}{FVvXGcxnRmGW5jQb3tw9kg}{01m_Bg7WRku3h2iP-9l0Kg}{10.6.23.154}{10.6.23.154:9300}{ml.machine_memory=66784632832, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {FVvXGcx}{FVvXGcxnRmGW5jQb3tw9kg}{01m_Bg7WRku3h2iP-9l0Kg}{10.6.23.154}{10.6.23.154:9300}{ml.machine_memory=66784632832, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)]])
[2023-04-18T03:55:06,506][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [FVvXGcx] publish_address {10.6.23.154:9200}, bound_addresses {10.6.23.154:9200}
[2023-04-18T03:55:06,507][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [FVvXGcx] started
[2023-04-18T03:55:09,266][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [FVvXGcx] Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
[2023-04-18T03:55:09,302][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [FVvXGcx] license [e6b59eec-31c8-4087-8612-863af70ea28f] mode [basic] - valid
[2023-04-18T03:55:09,312][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [FVvXGcx] recovered [31] indices into cluster_state
[2023-04-18T03:57:46,269][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [FVvXGcx] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[classification-index][2]] ...]).
```

The system status shows the following :

```
elastic_user@ulabsml5u:~$ systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2023-04-12 13:05:20 UTC; 5 days ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 1212 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elastic
 Main PID: 1212 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

If I use any curl command it shows:

```
elastic_user@ulabsml5u:/ml_data/at3/cache/ES/elasticsearch-6.6.0/bin$ curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?flat_settings=true&filter_path=persistent.archived*&pretty"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

I am in a fix as to how to proceed from here on. This instance is running on Bitvise SSH and it is an old version - elasticsearch-6.6.0

Comment: 1. Did you configure any custom bind settings? 2. Why such an ancient version? Not sure it will help here but both stability and errors messages have improved a lot over time.

Comment: This version is being used in a project that is in use. So, I did find out what the problem was, there was some orphaned java tasks running in background that I had to manually kill through root user. The ElasticSearch connection is up but it is showing  "Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[classification-index][0]] ...])." Not sure exactly what to do here. If I run a curl command to check the health status it just shows "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8889: Connection refused."

Comment: Unless you changed the default configuration, you want to curl port 9200. And I'm a bit surprised that not a single port for `Failed to bind to [9300-9400]` was still available for transport?

Comment: Still not able to connect even after changing port to 9200. Upon checking system status through "systemctl status elasticsearch.service", it returns the following: 

elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2023-04-12 13:05:20 UTC; 4 days ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 1212 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elastic
 Main PID: 1212 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Comment: Please update your post and add the full log.

Comment: I have updated the post as you asked for.

Comment: What if you try to curl `10.6.23.154:9200`? You seem to be doing something special with the binding

Comment: Tried running the command :

`elastic_user@ulabsml5u:/ml_data/at3/cache/ES/elasticsearch-6.6.0/bin$  curl 10.6.23.154:9200                  
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.6.23.154 port 9200: Connection refused`

Comment: You might have to add a bit more about the network: Is 10.6.23.154 the IP of the server or some other (virtual) interface you created? And what is the bind config you used in Elasticsearch?